# Is there a better practice for this code snippet?

Tags: ruby, return-value, block, watir

```
class MyWatir < Watir::Browser
  def with_watir_window(win)
    cw = window   #current window
    win.use
    yield
    cw.use
  end
  def qty     
    ret = nil                
    with_watir_window(@win2){
      ret = td(:id,'qty').text
    }      
    ret
  end 
end
```

In the second function, declaring `ret = nil` and stating it at the end seems ugly. Is there a cleaner way of returning the value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just return the inner value from the block. Also make sure that if an exception occurs, you leave in a consistent state:

```
class MyWatir < Watir::Browser
  def with_watir_window(win)
    cw = window   #current window
    win.use
    # the begin/end will evaluate to the value returned by `yield`.
    # if an exception occurs, the window will be reset properly and
    # there will be no return value.
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      cw.use
    end
  end

  def qty                     
    with_watir_window(@win2) do  
      td(:id,'qty').text
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Literally a perfect answer. Thanks